# aplicación de if en subcadenas usando python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo una cadena que solo contiene {[()]}.
La idea es que por cada llave corchete o paréntesis exista su correlativo cierre las posibles respuestas son true o false.
El problema que estoy hallando es que siempre sale true
les paso mi código

```
class Solution():
def isValid(self, s:str) -> bool:
    n=int (len(s)/2)
    while (n==0):
        for i in s:
            for j in reversed(s):
                if (i!=j):
                    return False
                break
        n-=1
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Una mirada rapida a los errores

Te devuelve verdadero por que n es mayor a 0 para cadenas vacías (si la cadena es vacía, `len(x)` es 0, y `0 / 2 == 0`). Si es 0, se ejecutará una sola vez por que le restas 1 a n.

También, estás asumiendo que las aperturas y cierres se encuentran al principio y final respectivamente y en orden. Pero ese podría no ser el caso.

De cualquier forma, sin lo anterior, un caracter de apertura nunca será igual a uno de cierre, por lo que `i!=j` no te va a servir.

##### Concepto

Un truco es hacer un seguimiento de las aperturas y cierres. Por ejemplo, al iterar sobre la cadena, si aparece una "{", le sumamos 1 a un contador que tendrá el número de aperturas cuyo cierre aún no se encontró. Si aparece "}", hay una menos abierta, por lo que restamos 1 al contador para reflejar el cambio.

Ahora, el contador de cada "{[(" al final de la iteración tendrá el número de cierres que están pendientes para cada tipo de apertura. Por ejemplo, para "{{[[}]", tendremos "{" = 1 y lo demás en 0.

Solo hay que ver que todos los contadores sean 0, si es positivo, significa que faltan cierres, si es negativo, significa que sobran.

**Pero** esta tecnica tiene un problema (que tardé en darme cuenta). La cadena "}{" daría verdadero, ya que 0 - 1 + 1 = 0. Sin embargo, no están bien cerradas. Eso significa que habrá que hacer un checkeo adicional para detectar este caso particular.
De hecho, podemos matar dos pajaros de un tiro haciendo que si el contador pasa a ser menor a 0 durante la iteración, directamente asumir que no es valido. Después de todo, aquellos cierres de más no se pueden revertir más adelante.

##### Código de ejemplo

```
def validar_cierres(cadena):
    par = 0
    corch = 0
    llaves = 0

    for char in cadena:
        if char == "(":
            par += 1
        elif char == "[":
            corch += 1
        elif char == "{":
            llaves += 1
        elif char == ")":
            par -= 1
        elif char == "]":
            corch -= 1
        elif char == "}":
            llaves -= 1

        if par < 0 or corch < 0 or llaves < 0:
            return False

    return par == 0 and corch == 0 and llaves == 0

for test in ["}{", "{[}]", "{[()]}", "{[()]}}}"]:
    print(test.ljust(10), "->", validar_cierres(test))
```

**Produce**

```
}{         -> False
{[}]       -> True
{[()]}     -> True
{[()]}}}   -> False
```

**Nota**
Por supuesto, el código puede ser mejorado utilizando diccionarios, pero no los usé para hacer el código más entendible como ejemplo.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta